# On the usage of "of which"

Tags: phrase-usage, prepositions, relative-pronouns

How do you use "of which" correctly after a comma? I saw a similar example in a textbook and tried to tweak it a little:

> "Our cost of A has been decreased from B to C just like the other ones, the retail prices **of which** we lowered from D to E."

Or is this more correct?

> "Our cost of A has been decreased from B to C just like the other ones, **of which** we lowered the retail prices from D to E."

Can I use "on which" in the same way I use "of which"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is the better one. It is, however, somewhat stiff and stilted. Most native speakers would probably say and write it this way:

> "Our cost for A has decreased from B to C, just as for the others, **whose** retail prices we lowered from D to E."

**Of which** is formal English.

Comment: I would have thought that the second one is better since 'of which' directly follows the object it's referring to, as opposed to the first where the reader has to go further back to get the reference of 'of which'. Is there perhaps a specific reason why the first one sounds better, or is it just idiomatic?

Comment: @Jerry: The usage changes when you change the form of the relative clause. **Whose** is a simple relative pronoun that refers to _the others_. The relative clause that uses **of which**, however, is the object of the preposition **of**; the relative pronoun **which** in this clause refers to _the **prices** of the others_, not to _the others_. That second sentence is very awkward and probably ungrammatical.

Comment: Reading the two sentences that way... yes, you're right, the second one does sound awkward.

Comment: @Bill Franke Wait, it's "cost for"? I thought it was "cost of," "prices of something," etc. Also, if I want to use "on which," should I say the same thing as the first sentence? "Our cost for A has been decreased from B to C just like the other ones, the retail prices on which we lowered from D to E."

Comment: @jess: "**The cost of A**" versus "**Our cost for A**". What's the problem? They're both idiomatic American English. The sentence in your comment is still not good. Use "whose prices we lowered from D to E" & you'll be perfectly understood.